# Edge extension executeScript doesn't have result?

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I want to get the selected text in Edge, but the result is always empty
browser.tabs.executeScript({code: "window.getSelection().toString();"}).then(result => {
 alert(result);
});

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known bug - see
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8504764/